How can I get assets from a folder via code in Unity?
I'm trying to get some assets from the folder Items, but it's not working. The folder structure is:
Assets -> Items -> Attack, Defense, etc. 

There's a folder for each type of item, and I want to get them all via code.
This is what I tried:
private List<ItemInstance> items; // List of all items in the game

void Start()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    // Load all ItemInstance assets from the "Items" folder
    items = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:ItemInstance", new[] { "Items" })
                 .Select(guid => AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid))
                 .Select(path => AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<ItemInstance>(path))
                 .ToList();
    #endif
}

void Update()
{
    foreach (ItemInstance item in items)
    {
        Debug.Log("item id: " + item.item.id + " item name: " + item.name);
    }
}

This did not work, I also tried with Assets/Items and to each folder, like Assets/Items/Attack, for example, but also did not work. The ItemInstance is a class I wrote to store an Item within, and I create these ItemInstances directly in the editor, right-clicking and going to Item -> AttackItem, or DefenseItem, etc.

It should definitely be "Assets/Items/Attack" according to the API ... anyway, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not reference them via the Inspector? And how is this supposed to work in a built app where UnityEditor is not available? You never store the results ... An why would you instantiate all items each and every frame?

Yes, i tried to reference them via Inspector but also does not work. That was my first and for sure is the best options, attach them in Inspector, but does not work. What happens is that i click in the button to select the items and its empty, doesn't appear any item, so i tryied to use this approach, but its still not working

Can't tell much without seeing your implementation of ItemInstance .. I also don't know what you tried and what exactly doesn't work means here .. please try to be specific and provide enough detail to reproduce the issue .. see [mcve]
